# SSIS Connection string not dynamically changing in child package for OLE DB Source

Tags: dynamic, ssis, connection-string

I am using VS2019 to create a SSIS project that will include a parent package that will run multiple child packages in sequence. The main packages reads a Task table and collects a connection string and passes it to the child package to use when reading a table using an OLE DB Source. I have some debugging steps created to insure that the connection string is being passed to the package parameter properly.
I have an expression setup on the Connection manager to get the parameter. I also have it set for DelayValidation = True. When I run the package the debug steps indicate that the connection string is being passed but the connection manager fails to use it. Here are some screen shots of my setup. I am looking to find a way to get the Connection manager to use the passed in Connection string.

[image]
[image]
[image]